# Taut strings in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, string, geodesics

In general relativity, a straight line is defined (or, in a sense, replaced?) [by the path a light beam takes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/601911/light-travels-in-straight-line-even-in-gravity). In Newtonian physics, another way to approximate a straight line between two points is to tighten a sufficiently light string between them. Is this method applicable in curved spacetime? Would such a string tend to a path light would take? What if there are multiple such paths?

Comment: It seems that you might be confusing space-time and space. Light has a geodesic worldline, it doesn't travel on a straight path through space. The last thing is not even meaningfull, space depends on a choice of split of the space-time. So you cannot use strings to replace worldlines.